# Is Runtime.getRuntime().Exec() environment diffrent from cmd env?

Tags: java, jar, cmd

I tried to run a jar from my code with the runtime command.The jar connects to another host through RMI.It throughs an exception and exits.

But when I open the jar from cmd it works fine.

The jar gets 5 arguments.

Code :

```
String runCommand = "java -jar WhiteboardStudent.jar "
        + "192.168.0.3" + " " 
        + "2000" + " " 
        + "2001" + " " 
        + "test" + " 0" ;
final Process proc = Runtime
        .getRuntime()
        .exec(runCommand,null,new File("util/"));
```

Command Prompt :

```
 java -jar WhiteboardStudent.jar 192.168.0.3 2000 2001 test 0
```

The code where the exception is thrown is here :

```
 Object proxy = registry.lookup("RWD");
 Whiteboard whiteboard = (Whiteboard)proxy;
```

I'm just stumped.any ideas?

The function that throws the exception :

```
Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry(
                hostname, Integer.parseInt(whiteboardPort)
                );
String serviceName = "RemoteWhiteboard" + sessionID;
Object proxy = registry.lookup(serviceName);
Whiteboard whiteboard = (Whiteboard)proxy;
int userid = whiteboard.userRegistry(userName, "");
Main mainFrame = new Main(sessions, sessionID,
    whiteboard,userid,"");
```

Comment: what's the exception?

Comment: a connection refused exception.

Comment: of everything that could go wrong, that is not what i expected.  We will need to see the code in your jar file; specifically, the area where that exception is being thrown

Comment: Can you reach host 192.168.0.3?  Are the parameters 2000 and 2001 port numbers? Is there a process at the remote host listening on the correct ports?  `Connection Refused` means there was no process listening at the server when you tried to connect.

Comment: Whether it is or it isn't, RMI has nothing to do with it in any way shape or form.

Comment: @JimGarrison it a wierd exception.because it's almost random,even on the same system it comes and goes.And I'm sure it's related to RMI,but not why is this happening.Another question would be is RMI dependent on firewalls,privacy setting,or something that I don't know?
(I know about security manager and I use it)

Comment: @RussellUhl I added the relevant part of the code,the other parts are unrelevant.

Comment: 1) Read (and implement) *all* the recommendations of [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html).  That might solve the problem.  If not, it should provide more information as to the reason it failed.  Then ignore that it refers to `exec` and build the `Process` using a `ProcessBuilder`.  Also break a `String arg` into `String[] args` to account for arguments which themselves contain spaces. 2) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score -1):

My suggestion is try the absolute path in your code:

```
String runCommand = "java -jar /c/users/xxx/WhiteboardStudent.jar "
    + "192.168.0.3" + " " 
    + "2000" + " " 
    + "2001" + " " 
    + "test" + " 0" ;
```